# Erlang - Problems with list/tuple hierarchy after recursion

Tags: recursion, erlang

The resulting tree of this recursion is not what I what, which probably proves that I don't fully understand the behaviour of lists/tuples in recursion. If someone could explain what I did wrong in this example and also explain the right way to think I'd be very grateful.

```
move([],{Main, One, Two}) ->
    {Main, One, Two};
move([X|Xr], {Main, One, Two}) ->
    [{Main, One, Two}, move(Xr, single(X, {Main, One, Two}))].
```

Desired result (one list containing 3 tuples):

```
[{[a,b],[],[]}, {[a],[b],[]}, {[],[b],[a]}, {[b],[],[a]}]
```

Actual Result(a list containing a tuple and a list, containing a tuple and a list...):

```
[{[a,b],[],[]},[{[a],[b],[]},[{[],[b],[a]},[{[b],[],[a]}]]]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. The `|` instead of `,` as @nmichaels mentioned.
2. The function `move/2` returns a **list** so the terminating clause must also return a list. This is not seen in your example as the first problem hides it.

So the resulting code would be:

```
move([X|Xr], {Main, One, Two}) ->
    [{Main, One, Two} | move(Xr, single(X, {Main, One, Two}))];
move([], {Main, One, Two}) ->
    [{Main, One, Two}].
```

I flipped the order of the clauses as I personally prefer writing them this way. No fundamental difference in this case. I am assuming that `single/2` returns a tuple.

You can actually optimise this code by removing all knowledge of the tuple from `move/2` as it never actually *uses* the internal structure. So:

```
move([X|Xr], Tuple) ->
    [Tuple | move(Xr, single(X, Tuple))];
move([], Tuple) ->
    [Tuple].
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `|` instead of `,` when composing a list like that:

```
move([X|Xr], {Main, One, Two}) ->
    [{Main, One, Two} | move(Xr, single(X, {Main, One, Two}))].
```

The recursive call returns a list, which will just nest deeper and deeper unless you use `|` to flatten them out a bit. It's the same concept as in the pattern match `[X|Xr]` just with a reversed operation.

Comment: I tried that, but that will result in this, which is better, but not perfect:
`[{[a,b],[],[]},{[a],[b],[]},{[],[b],[a]}|{[b],[],[a]}]`  The '|' is still there in the answer.

Comment: It applies X to the lists Main, One and Two, and returns {MainX, OneX, TwoX}, a tuple with 3 lists.

Comment: Solved it! I added an accumulator (I think), an empty list where I store the states instead of adding them on the way up from the recursion.

        `move([],Tuple, Y) -> append(Y,[Tuple]);
        move([X|Xr], Tuple, Y) -> move(Xr, single(X, Tuple), append(Y,[Tuple])).`

Is it correct to say that this is tail recursive?